# Why is this MYSQL fulltext search not giving a score?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a record like this, in a table (`squirrel_users`) that has a full-text index on `email`.

```
+-----------+----------------------------+
| record_id | email                      |
+-----------+----------------------------+
|      7065 | s.j.e.hennessyexample.com  |
+-----------+----------------------------+
```

However, if I do a MATCH on email, in boolean mode, I don't get a score:

```
mysql> SELECT record_id, email, 
(MATCH (email) AGAINST ("+s.j.e.hennessyexample.com" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS score 
FROM squirrel_users 
WHERE record_id = 7065 ORDER BY score DESC; 
+-----------+----------------------------+-------+
| record_id | email                      | score |
+-----------+----------------------------+-------+
|      7065 | s.j.e.hennessyexample.com  |     0 |
+-----------+----------------------------+-------+
```

Can anyone see why the score is zero here, where I'm doing `+<exact saved data>`?  is it something to do with the full stops maybe?

Aha - if I wrap the term in quotes then it works:

```
mysql> SELECT record_id, email, 
(MATCH (email) AGAINST ("+\"s.j.e.hennessyexample.com\"" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS score 
FROM squirrel_users 
WHERE record_id = 7065 ORDER BY score DESC;
+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+
| record_id | email                      | score              |
+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+
|      7065 | s.j.e.hennessyexample.com  | 25.576061248779297 |
+-----------+----------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So what's happening with the full stops then - are they breaking it up so it's treated like separate words?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you have answered your own question (which is also explained by the duplicate link).

Comment: I think it's **related** to that, in that I could address it by making `.` a "word character" for innodb fulltext searches, but I'm not sure it's a duplicate.  Thanks though, I think that will lead me towards the solution.

Comment: I reopened your question since you disagreed with the duplicate mark.  Yes, I think that making dot a word character would resolve your problem, _but_ it also would mean that the last word in the sentence `Max asks questions.` would be `questions.`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm actually now thinking of going in the opposite direction and removing all nonword characters out of my text before I save it in the columns that get FT indexed.  Now I just need to find a list of the nonword characters - do you know how to get that by any chance?

Comment: Where are you planning to do this cleanup?  The regex marker for a non word character is usually `\W`, but it depends on the tool/language you are using.  So, roughly replacing `\W` with empty string would do what you have in mind.

Comment: For the classes that are indexed, I have special columns in different tables just to fulltext index the records' data.  The cleanup would be done in there.  With `\W`, i read somewhere that it doesn't take utf8 into account, ie `\W` would not pull in letter characters from other languages.  In other words, replacing `\W` with `""` would leave lots of non-English letters.  Do you know if that is the case?  I'm currently building a list of all the characters in the indexed columns, so I can test this.

Comment: Not sure about that, but you can always use a negated character class, e.g. `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`, to represent anything which is not a word character.

Comment: That's the same problem with UTF8 though isn't it, that for example "Ö" would be treated as non-word char because it's not between A and Z.

Comment: That's not how a negative character class works.  What I wrote is saying match anything which is _not_ one of those characters.  So UTF-8 characters would fail that range, and therefore be matched.

Comment: I've made a faulty assumption here - I thought that "\W" would pull in non-english UTF8 characters, but it doesn't.  Sorry.  I just tested it like this (in Ruby):  `word = "FOÖ.BÀR; word.gsub(/\W/,"x");` the result is  `"FOÖxBÀR"`, so that is doing what I want after all. thanks!"